# Angular $HTTP works with CORS and application/x-www-form-urlencoded but gets OPTIONS 404 with application/json

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, cors

I've got a Node + ExpressJS with CORS working through [this middleware](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cors). I'm having trouble working with POST.

This works:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: domain + '/services/statemap/create',
    data: data
}).
```

But this doesn't:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: domain + '/services/statemap/create',
    data: data
}).
```

I get OPTIONS with an 404 error. Any ideas?

Server code:

```
var  cors = require('cors')...

// first version (not working)
app.post('/services/statemap/create', cors(),services.createStateMapPost);

// second version (not working)
app.post('/services/statemap/create', cors({methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS', allowedHeaders:'Accept,Content-Type,Origin,Authorization'}),services.createStateMapPost);
```

Comment: Your server either isn't configured properly, or the path you are using to your server is not correct.  If your server is actually receiving the call, it is rejecting the request outright.  You'll have to show your server code for further help.

Comment: Sure, I've added the endpoint code

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the preflight request.  After glancing at the documentation for the CORS middleware you are using, you probably just need to include something like this in your server code:

`app.options('/services/statemap/create', cors());`

Also, I would strongly suggest that you NOT use a library to handle CORS server-side.  It's *really* easy to properly acknowledge CORS requests in your responses, and middleware such as the one you are using just makes this all more confusing, IMHO.